# The data types varchar and datetimeoffset are incompatible in the add operator

Tags: sql, sql-server

While I am trying to use dynamic query code in my SQL statement

```
Declare @Start datetimeoffset;
Declare @End datetimeoffset;
Declare @SqlCommand nvarchar(Max);

Set @Start = '2013-05-17 10:00:04.500 +00:00';
Set @End = '2013-09-17 10:00:04.500 +00:00'
Set @SqlCommand = 'Select * from Test where TimeLine > '+ @Start+' AND TimeLine < '+@End

Exec(@SqlCommand)
```

I get below message saying

> Msg 402, Level 16, State 1, Line 8
>   The data types varchar and datetimeoffset are incompatible in the add operator.

please guide me the correct usage.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to cast the DateTimeOffset values to varchars.
Also, you are missing the additional quotes.

Something like

```
Declare @Start datetimeoffset = '2013-05-17 10:00:04.500 +00:00'
Declare @End datetimeoffset = '2013-09-17 10:00:04.500 +00:00'
Declare @SqlCommand nvarchar(Max)

Set @SqlCommand = 'Select * from Test where SampleTime > '''+ CAST(@Start AS VARCHAR(50))+''' AND SampleTime < '''+CAST(@End AS VARCHAR(50)) + ''''

SELECT @SqlCommand
```

### [SQL Fiddle DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/6939)

Answer (score 1):

You should add `''` as below and cast `@Start / @End` to varchar

```
Declare @Start datetimeoffset;
Declare @End datetimeoffset;
Declare @SqlCommand nvarchar(Max);

Set @Start = '2013-05-17 10:00:04.500 +00:00';
Set @End = '2013-09-17 10:00:04.500 +00:00'
Set @SqlCommand = 'Select * from Test where SampleTime > '''+ cast(@Start as varchar(100))+''' AND SampleTime < '''+cast(@End as varchar(100))+''' '

Exec(@SqlCommand)
```